# How to make QPushButton to be in checked state by default?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I am using `QPushButton.setCheckable(True)`, by default button is not checked, but I want it to be checked from the beginning. I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the name says, `setCheckable` sets if the button is **checkable** or not.

[`setChecked()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop) sets whether a *checkable* button is actually **checked** or not.

Remember that most Qt classes inherit from a superclass (so it also inherits all its properties and functions), you can check the inheritance in the header of the documentation, and there's also a link named "List of all members, including inherited members".

The full inheritance of QPushButton is:

QPushButton > QAbstractButton > QWidget > QObject, QPaintDevice

So, it means that QPushButtons also has all functions and properties of QAbstractButton, QWidget, QObject *and* QPaintDevice.
This also means that if you really want to know what a class does, you should better study **all** the documentation related to **all** the classes it inherits from.